# Custom drawer menu used in all pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to cross platform development using Xamarin and currently I'm into the "trial and error"-phase.

I want to create my own drawer menu, that goes from bottom and upwards on slide. The menu will have different stop stages since the buttons (navigations) will be grouped by some logical things such as "Favorites", "Frequently used" etc. where each row (group) will contain the buttons.

Is it possible to create a "master page" with a header and also the footer which is the drawer?

I stumbled upon the ControlTemplate, however to me that only seem to be a master layout that can be used in pages to get the same look-and-feel without redundant style coding. As per Xamarin documentation

> Control templates provide a clean separation between the appearance of a page and its content, enabling the creation of pages that can easily be themed.

But I need to add some behavior to it such as the sliding animation etc. and I would really not like to add a container in each xaml-file that I place the drawer menu in within each xaml.cs file.

Is there a good way of achieving something like this?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Slide Over Kit may help. It is a free plug in that allows you to create slide in panels from any direction.

https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit